# System priorities for a good value set-up

Tags: memory-management

Hi This is my first post as a newbie on this forum, so forgive me if I get any of the rules wrong. I'm a film maker who's just packed in the day job with ambitions to make a micro-budget feature film set in 18th C Scotland. Ridiculous optimism! I've been working on creating CGI town scapes and buildings with Blender for over a year, with encouraging results. Now I need to invest in upgrading my kit. I know I shouldn't ask about specific items, but what I'm struggling to understand is what aspects would help blender modelling and rendering, and what are irrelevant. (I'm Mac based). Should I spend on masses of RAM? Flash versus Fusion memory? Graphics cards? Processor speed? Can anyone tell me what I should prioritise with my hard-won cash?

Comment: Hardware questions are considered off topic here, you should try Blender Artists forum instead. Also you don't mention which render engine you use. Assuming it is Cycles you should probably be investing on good graphics cards if you intend to do a lot of GPU rendering. And if you are serious about it you should probably ditch Mac based platforms

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I will check out the Artists Forum, and bear your points in mind.